# How do I handle an 'undefined' return from the console when I set a method to an object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, undefined

I have an object called Message that has a built in method called .show() which takes a string as its input. When I call .show() on my Message class, a bullet pointed list item with my string input appears in the unordered list (classname = chat) in my browser.

In the console, Message.show('string') returns **undefined**. For practice-sake, I have deleted .show() so I can learn to build it.

Code:

```
 Message.prototype.show = function (text) {           
     $('.chat').append('<li>' + text + '</li>');
 }
```

However, I get a *TypeError saying I cannot set property 'show' of undefined.* I understand I that it is expecting a function in return, but does this mean I can not give the Message class a method it used to have? Do I have syntactical errors in using prototype or appending a list item? Is there a better way of doing this?

I am stuck.. any help is appreciated. Thank you so much!

Comment: I am not sure I understand... but of course `Message.show('string')` RETURNS undefined.  There is no return statement in that function.

Comment: Where (and how) do you define Message?

Comment: @Steve: There is no `show` property on the `Message` (function?) object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to define `function Message()` before you can add a `.show()` method to it.

If I'm not mistaken, what you're looking for is this:

```
 // Define the function
 function Message() {

 }

 // Add prototype methods
 Message.prototype.show = function (text) {           
     $('.chat').append('<li>' + text + '</li>');
 }

 // Usage:
 var msg = new Message();
 msg.show("Hello there.");
```

You can even add some extra's to it like this (not tested):

```
 function Message() {
      this.chatWindow = $(".chat");
 }

 Message.prototype.render = function (text) {
      return $('<li>' + text + '</li>');
 }

 Message.prototype.show = function (text) {           
     this.chatWindow.append(this.render(text));
 }

 // Usage:
 var msg = new Message();
 msg.show("Hello there.");
```

Comment: Why is `Message.prototype;` necessary?

Comment: @joeframbach Good catch, it's not. I'll remove it.

Comment: This does. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You have to initialize something with `Message` and cannot access its methods directly.

For example:

```
var message = new Message();
message.show('test');
```